# Jquery DIV transition (or CSS)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, transition, slidedown

I am currently looking for a way to slideDown or animate a div to transition from the top to the content height on the page load (undefined).  Is this possible or can it only be done with a user event?  It is okay if CSS is used in conjunction.

Comment: I take it jQuery's `.slideDown()` method doesn't do what you want? Are you saying you want the entire element to move to the bottom of the page with a sliding motion? What if this takes it off the bottom of the screen? It would help if you could show your markup.

Answer (score 0):

To slide Down you can use $(selector).slideDown(milli Seconds/"fast"/"slow"); . if still have problem post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this inside an onload handler:

```
$("#yourDivIdHere").css("position","absolute").animate({
    top : $("body").height()
}, 3000);
```

That is, set the div to have absolute positioning and then animate its `top` position to the height of the document body. You may need to add a little extra to allow for margins. And obviously you can specify a delay other than 3000ms as appropriate.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a6gGs/